# Sharpen a section of a video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I did a video shoot of a panel discussion. There are four people on the panel. Two to the left are in focus, two to the right are not. Is there a way to isolate the people to the right (not in focus) and use sharpening techniques on them?

Comment: Not really although there is a fast blur function that you can invert to create an edge enhancement effect, but de-blurring is mostly not successful. Try the sharpen node in the compositor, it will be slow but might give the effect that you want.

Comment: My question was a two parter. First, isolate a section of the video that needed sharpening. Second. Then sharpen it. Your way would cause too much contrast to sections of the video that do not need it. I need step-by-step instructions to sharpen half a video frame.

Comment: You can use a mask in Blender to seperate sections of the screen.